# Moving an object to the left side of the window

Tags: html, css

I know that moving something to the right side or the bottom side of the HTML page will bring up the drag-bar when it is going off the screen with `overflow: auto`. Is it possible to make the dragbar appear when you move something off the screen to the *left* side?

Comment: dragging something off the screen to the right/bottom will bring up a scroll-bar. can you bring up the scroll bar when you move something off the screen to the left side of the browser.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: I am still confuse what you asking.   I guess you can you something like "overflow-x: scroll"

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't the page automatically do this if the content is wider than the window size?

Comment: @JennyC do you want anything like http://jsfiddle.net/TcmLV/2/ ?

Comment: my position is set as absolute, if i change it to relative its super funky, why is that?